# Pass a SQL variable into an 'IN' clause through stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My variable looks like this:

```
DECLARE @number AS NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @number = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
```

What I have in my WHERE statement is this:

```
WHERE V.client IN (@number)
```

My `V.Client` column is an integer. What I am trying to do is remove the '' from the @number and make it look like 1,2,3,4,5,6. I have tried to do this,

```
',' + @number + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(V.client AS VARCHAR) + ',%'
```

but it only returns results for 1 and not the other numbers.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I can do?

Comment: Pass in a table valued parameter is one option. Or use dynamic sql.

Comment: Use a "splitter()" function to turn the string parameter into a table add join against that.  There are a few splitter functions here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Don't use delimited strings in SQL. Just Don't. There are other, better ways. Using A table valued parameter or an xml parameter are probably the best options, another would be using a string splitting function, string manipulation like the one you've tried and dynamic sql are also options, though probably the worst.

Answer (score 3):

Another option

```
DECLARE @number AS nvarchar(1000)
SET @number = '1,2,3,4,5,6'

...
WHERE V.client IN (
                    Select RetVal = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
                    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@Number,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                  )
```

If 2016+,  use **string_split()**

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic sql is the most common option, here's a snippet how to use it

```
DECLARE @number AS nvarchar(1000)
SET @number = N'1,2,3,4,5,6'

declare @cmd nvarchar(1000) = N'select case when 1 in ' + Quotename(@number, '()') + ' then 1 else 0 end'

exec sp_executesql @cmd
```

which will prepare following query

```
select case when 1 in (1,2,3,4,5,6) then 1 else 0 end
```

Other options you can consider:
Split the string and use standard sql queries. 
In new sql server there is function string_split which make exacly what you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.
In older versions you can create custom fuction doing exactly the same thing [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)